# Quais são as diferenças entre require() e library()?

Tags: r

Em R, quais são as diferenças entre `require()` e `library()`, se houverem? Quando devo incluir o `require()` e quando devo incluir o `library()`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A informação a seguir consta do próprio help da função `require` do `R`:

> library(package) and require(package) both load the namespace of the package with name package and attach it on the search list. require is designed for use inside other functions; it returns FALSE and gives a warning (rather than an error as library() does by default) if the package does not exist

Ou seja, se sugere que `require` seja utilizada dentro de outras funções, pois ela retorna um warning caso o pacote a ser carregado não conste no sistema. O comando `library`, por padrão, retorna um erro quando o pacote não está instalado.

Não há diferença para quem for usar estas funções no dia a dia. As duas fazem a mesma coisa.

Answer (score 1):

Na execução pura destes comandos não há diferença, mas com o comando `require` é possível automatizar a verificação da presença do pacote e somente depois disso, acontece instalação deste, pois ele retorna TRUE ou FALSE, segue exemplo para instalar o pacote "datamap":

```
inst_pacote <- require(datamap)
if (inst_pacote == FALSE) {
        install.packages("datamap")
}
```